# Angular JS assign to scope from Ajax then calculate

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I need to do some calculations from data from Ajax and present the result.

```
Data.getOrder(2)
            .success(function(data)
            {
             $scope.contactList = data;


            })
```

Then I have this :

```
$timeout(function(){

        angular.forEach($scope.contactList,function(value,index){
            ...do something
        })

    }, 2000);
```

It works fine but is this the best way to do it?? Is there no other way to make sure that when I work with $scope.contactList it wont be null?

The ajax call result :

```
[{"amount":150,"percent":15},{"amount":150,"percent":15}]
```

I need to cycle 
and do this

```
cycle 1 - amount * percent = total 
cycle 2 - amount * percent = total2 


 $cope.grandtotal = total+total2
```

I know I could, for example use a custom filter but I am using ngTable and I cant get it right.

```
 <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table">
                <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
                    <td data-title="'Pedido'" sortable="'Order_id'">
                        [[user.Order_id]]
                    </td>
                    <td data-title="'Producto'" sortable="'Product'">
                        [[user.Product]]
                    </td>
                    <td data-title="'QTY'" sortable="'amount'">
                        [[user.amount]]
                    </td>

                    <td data-title="'Descuento'" sortable="'percent'">
                        % [[user.percent]]
                    </td>
                    <td data-title="'Total pagar'" sortable="'percent'">


                        $  [[ (user.amount * user.cost)- (user.amount * user.cost)* 0.15]]
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Thanks

**UPDATE**

```
Data.getOrder(2)
            .success(function(data)
            {
             $scope.contactList = data;
                    $scope.load = year+" "+nam;

               // processData()

             //

            }).then(function(){


            processData()

            })

function processData() {
            angular.forEach($scope.contactList, function(value, index) {
                alert(value.amount);
            });
        }
```

The above works fine, is it done right? But how do I add error function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a timeout is likely to cause problems. You already know when the data is available, so just process it then.

```
Data.getOrder(2)
    .success(function(data) {
         $scope.contactList = data;
    })
    .error(function(err) {
         // Handle the error.
    })
    .then(processData);

function processData() {
    angular.forEach($scope.contactList, function(value, index) {
        alert(value.amount);
    });
}
```

Comment: That will depend upon what's in your `...do something` code.

Answer (score 0):

ajax call returns a promise, so you can levarage the promise return from your ajax call;
use .then() method

```
 Data.getOrder(2)
        .then(function(data) {
             $scope.contactList = data;


        }).then(function(){

 angular.forEach($scope.contactList, function(value,index) {
            ...do something
        });
});
```

Comment: Hi ! thanks it didnt work, it gives me undefined. I updated my answer with whats working.